# How do I resolve this error while installing Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubygems, jekyll

I followed [this page](http://www.garron.me/en/bits/install-jekyll-on-ubuntu.html) and installed Jekyll, but when I tried to run Jekyll I got this error:

```
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'liquid' (~> 2.5.5) - did find: [liquid-3.0.1,liquid-2.6.1] (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/home/ali/.gem/ruby/2.1.0:/var/lib/gems/2.1.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.1.0:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/2.1:/usr/share/rubygems-integration/all', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1311:in `block in activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1300:in `activate_dependencies'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1282:in `activate'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:67:in `block in gem'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:66:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:22:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates that the version of the liquid Gem that jekyll needs is lower than the ones you have installed. You should look into installing the right version which is v2.5.5.

```
gem install liquid -v 2.5.5
```

Should fix this.